# Are women the most fertile right after puberty

Tags: obstetrics, fertility

The title basically sums up my question.
Just wondering, are women the most fertile right after puberty? Aldo, do they see no increase in fertility during the rest of their life, or does their fertility go up during their early 20s?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question right:

[WebMD](http://www.m.webmd.com/baby/features/fertility-101):

> Fertility peaks in your 20s.

So yes, young women are more fertile after puberty in their 20's. If you consider that after, as it would be around 7-18 years afterward puberty if they got puberty in their 13-14 year range.

And:

> Most women hit their fertile peak between
>   the ages of 23 and 31, though the rate at which women conceive begins
>   to dip slightly in their late 20s. Around age 31, fertility starts to
>   drop more quickly — by about 3 percent per year — until you hit 35 or
>   so.

After the peak in fertility of their 20's their fertility goes down again.